# Bluetooth BLE programming import error

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, importerror

everyone !

I am designing a **Bluetooth BLE 4.0** application and I firstly copied a sample application from the internet to see how to develop it.
I expect to see somebody else to write search and display and do some works on BLE device. And everything nears OK, except these two underlined errors.

[image]

So where should I import these two classes?

Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Comment: is this Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: it is Eclipse Neon

Comment: hmm i'm not sure, but ScanCallback and ScanResult were only added in API level 21. do you have API 21 installed? and have you set your project build target to >= 18?

Comment: yeah, i have not installed API 21, thank you @ginomempin, and now i am downloading API 21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ScanCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanCallback.html) and [ScanResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanResult.html) were only added in API 21.
Make sure that API 21 is installed and also the project's build target is set to >= 18.

Comment: yeah, after install API 21 to the Eclipse neon, these two errors disappear.